# ZeroMQ setsockopt and getsockopt returing invalid argument

Tags: c++, zeromq

```
int main () 
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);

    //  Socket to talk to clients
    zmq::socket_t push (context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    unsigned long long hwm;
    size_t hwmsz;
    push.getsockopt( ZMQ_HWM, &hwm, &hwmsz);
    cout << "HWM:" << hwm << endl;
}
```

Executing the above code is resulting in the following exception using zeromq version 4.1.4. Any socket option is resulting in invalid argument for both `setsockopt()` and `getsockopt()`.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Use int instead of long long for the hwm variable

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your code against the API specification for details:

```
socket_t::socket_t(        context_t  &context,
                           int         type
                           );
```

maps onto ZeroMQ API:

```
void *zmq_socket (   void *context,
                     int   type
                     );
```

And

```
void socket_t::getsockopt( int         option_name,
                           void       *option_value,
                           size_t     *option_len
                           );
```

maps onto ZeroMQ API:

```
int zmq_getsockopt ( void   *socket,
                     int     option_name,
                     void   *option_value,
                     size_t *option_len
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: option length must be initialized.

```
size_t hwmsz = sizeof(unsigned long long);
```

Second thing:

ZMQ_HWM - is this a deprecated option?

try to get the values of ZMQ_SNDHWM and ZMQ_RCVHWM (they are int`s)

Comment: in zeromq 4.x the valid constant is ZMQ_HWM. Using ZMQ_SNDHWM and ZMQ_RCVHWM is throwing compilation errors.

Comment: @Mahi, current stable release is v4.1.3, why do you use 4.1.4? also check zmq.h: mine shows that there is no ZMQ_HWM. http://pastebin.com/3FKGw6Pv